# Trigger a class when uploading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

By adding a class to a button I trigger a popup on my page. If I'm allowing the user to upload a profile image, how do I add the class when the user uploads the profile image?

Basically I want trigger the pop-up when the user selects his profile image. So I want to add the class in to the < form > or into the `.change` function. Not sure if this is possible but this is what I need.

Usually I use the class as

```
<button type="button" class="myWindow">Button</button>
```

This is where I need to add  class="myWindow" when the user selects his profile image:

```
<form name="myForm" action="profilePic.php" method="post" id="addProfilePic" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="well">
    <label for="file">Imagename:</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
</form>
<script>
$(function(){
   $("#file").change(function (){
     $("#addProfilePic").submit();
   });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: You mean the button click should trigger the popup?

Comment: Use $("#addProfilePic").trigger( "click" );

Comment: @LearningNeverStops : Ideally I would like the pop-up to be triggered when ` $("#file").change(function (){` is executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.trigger` to trigger a event

```
$(function(){
   $("#file").change(function (){
     $("#addProfilePic").trigger( "click" ); 
   });
 });
```

Comment: Thanks. What happens to the submit `$("#addProfilePic").submit();`?Where should I add the class? It is within the  <form> tags?

Comment: I want trigger the pop-up when the user selects his profile image. So I'm looking for a way to add the class into the <form> or to the `.change(function (){`. Is this possible?

Comment: Submit is not a function in js